# Make pylint throw a warning at desired locations

Tags: python, warnings, pylint

I want to make pylint throw a warning at a custom point in my code without adding bugs to the code.

For example I created a function my_fun() with a hardcoaded output so I can call it elsewhere ex:

```py
def get_value():
    return 7
```

I want to put something in my code to throw a warning so i do not leave it like this by accident.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and found that pylint will give a warning on the the word TODO ie

```py
def get_value()
    return 7
    # TODO: remove hardcoded value
```

will give a warning of type `W0511:fixme` with the message `TODO: remove hardcoded value`

if you want to suppress this message without deleting it then

```py
# TODO_: remove hardcoded value
```

will give no message